# Filling a fixed number (x) of new columns with tolist() function which sometimes contains less items (< x)

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, tolist

I am using tolist() to split up a 8-item-list in 1 column ('modelGreeks') into 8 new columns in that same dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['modelGreeks'].tolist(), index=df.index)
df[['IV_model', 59, 'Price_model', 61, 62, 63, 64, 'undPrice']] = pd.DataFrame(df['modelGreeks'].tolist(), index=df.index)
```

This the list that I normally get in the column 'modelGreeks':

```
(0.2953686167703842, -1.9317880628477724e-14, 1.4648640549124297e-15, 0.0, 6.240571011994176e-13, 1.1840837166645831e-15, -1.4648640549124297e-15, 10.444000244140625)
```

9 out of 10 times this works perfectly. But sometimes the data that I retrieve via an API is not perfect/complete. Instead of the expected list with 8 items in column 'modelGreeks' it provides a 'None'-value in that field and I get the following error message on the code execution of the second code line (logically since it tries to fill 8 columns with just 1 value available:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I am looking for a solution where the 8 new columns will be created and filled anyway, e.g. with 0 or NaN or None.

Hope somebody can help out. Thanks in advance for your efforts.

The following code works:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['IV_model', 59, 'Price_model', 61, 62, 63, 64, 'undPrice','modelGreeks'])
df1['modelGreeks'] = [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], None, None, None, None]
df1[['IV_model', 59, 'Price_model', 61, 62, 63, 64, 'undPrice']] = df1['modelGreeks'].apply(pd.Series)
```

It returns:

```
   IV_model  59  Price_model  61  62  63  64  undPrice  modelGreeks
0  NaN       NaN NaN          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
1  NaN       NaN NaN          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN       None
2  NaN       NaN NaN          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN       None
3  NaN       NaN NaN          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN       None
4  NaN       NaN NaN          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN       None
```

And that is good. The only problem is that on certain moments the dataset which I receive via the API from Interactive Brokers will only provide a scalar None value in all the rows of the column modelGreeks. If I apply that to the test case then i get the error message again ("ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['IV_model', 59, 'Price_model', 61, 62, 63, 64, 'undPrice','modelGreeks'])
df1['modelGreeks'] = [None, None, None, None, None]
df1[['IV_model', 59, 'Price_model', 61, 62, 63, 64, 'undPrice']] = df1['modelGreeks'].apply(pd.Series)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/floris/PycharmProjects/ib_insync/test1.py", line 9, in <module>
df1[['IV_model', 59, 'Price_model', 61, 62, 63, 64, 'undPrice']] = df1['modelGreeks'].apply(pd.Series)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3367, in __setitem__
self._setitem_array(key, value)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3389, in _setitem_array
raise ValueError('Columns must be same length as key')
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

In this case I would like to see also only NaN values in the 8 columns.

Comment: I don't understand, what are you trying to do: the dataframe with the column `modelGreeks` and the dataframe with the columns `'IV_model', 59, 'Price_model', 61, 62, 63, 64, 'undPrice'` should be different dataframes, but they are both denoted as `df` in your question?

Comment: I want to transport the 8 data-points which are now combined in the field 'modelGreeks' to 8 separate columns in the same dataframe, for usage later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a new DataFrame but convert the list column into a Series:

```
df[['IV_model', 59, 'Price_model', 61, 62, 63, 64, 'undPrice']] = df['modelGreeks'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['IV_model', 59, 'Price_model', 61, 62, 63, 64, 'undPrice','modelGreeks'])
df['modelGreeks'] = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [1,2,None,4,5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [None], None, [None,None,None,None,None]]
df[['IV_model', 59, 'Price_model', 61, 62, 63, 64, 'undPrice']] = df['modelGreeks'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
   IV_model   59  Price_model  ...   64  undPrice                     modelGreeks
0       1.0  2.0          3.0  ...  7.0       8.0        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
1       1.0  2.0          NaN  ...  7.0       8.0     [1, 2, None, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
2       1.0  2.0          3.0  ...  7.0       NaN           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
3       NaN  NaN          NaN  ...  NaN       NaN                          [None]
4       NaN  NaN          NaN  ...  NaN       NaN                            None
5       NaN  NaN          NaN  ...  NaN       NaN  [None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in all cases EXCEPT: when all 5 elements in line 2 are [None]. In that case I still get the error: "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"

Comment: Any thoughts on how this might also work for:  df['modelGreeks'] = [[None], [None], [None], [None], [None]]

Comment: I added this case to the test (row 5): it works for me (pandas 0.24.2).

Comment: I just saw that you said `[[None], [None], [None], [None], [None]]` instead of `[None, None, None, None, None]`, but the former also works and results in `[None]` in columns 1..5 and `NaN` in 6..8.

Comment: But why we suddenly talk about **5** values, in your question you said **8** and IIUC it'll be either a list of 8 values or just one scalar None value (i.e. no list)?

Comment: Correct. 5 values was referring to the number of rows in your example (and should have been 6 I now realise). In my test (also panda 0.24.2), which is a copy of yours, when all rows in the column 'modelGreeks' contain just one scalar None value, I get the error message. df1['modelGreeks'] = [None, None, None, None, None] doesn't work and as soon as one of the items contains a list of 8 it works. The following does work:  df1['modelGreeks'] = [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], None, None, None, None]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get what you mean. Where do you need to set `df1['modelGreeks'] = [None, None, None, None, None]` in your program? This fills the **whole column** `modelGreeks`with values (5 rows). If you want to set a single value in your dataframe (e.g. for test purposes, say in row with index 5), you must use `df.at[5,'modelGreeks'] = ...`

Comment: I have added the code above in my question. The column modelGreeks is filled from an API generated dataset. Most times the API fills the column modelGreeks with a list of 8 values. But in some cases it fills all rows with just the None value. This is blocking the code from working as from that line since the error message kicks in.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't work when the all values in `modelGreeks` are None and all other columns are empty. In this case, however, nothing needs to be done anyway, so you can just test `df.dropna(how='all').empty` and then only do the filling of the columns if this returns `False`.

Comment: I got this to work in test with an if else statement.  Case closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are converting the values you get to list, I would suggest checking the length of the list first. And if it is less than 8, you can append 0s to it. Something like this:

```
lst = df['modelGreeks'].tolist()
lst += [0]*(8 - len(lst))
df[['IV_model', 59, 'Price_model', 61, 62, 63, 64, 'undPrice']] = pd.DataFrame(np.array(lst).reshape(1,8), index=df.index)
```

I have used np.array.reshape to make sure there are no shape mismatch errors.
If I understood your question correctly, this may help. I am sure there must be a cooler way to do this, others may be able to help you on that, but this should also achieve the task.

Comment: Thanks, certainly a step in the right direction, one small further hurdle, I get the following error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 512 into shape (1,8)

Answer (score 2):

The first error you presented,

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

would be outputted when the values you provided and the number of columns do not match up.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'teams': [['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],
                ['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG']]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
print (df2)

df2[['team1','team2', 'team3']] = pd.DataFrame(df2.teams.values.tolist(), index= df2.index)
print (df2)
```

In this case 'team3' is not needed. Just a reacap on smth that you probably already know.

Then let's replace the last entry in the list with None:

```
d1 = {'teams': [['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],
                ['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],None]}
Produced error:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

To remove the None entry just do:

```
df3 = df2.replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan).dropna()
```

This shouldn't be a problem since they are not providing any valuable information.

So as a final example, you would have smth like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d1 = {'teams': [['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],
                ['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],None]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df3 = df2.replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan).dropna()

df2[['team1','team2']] = pd.DataFrame(df3.teams.values.tolist(), index= df3.index)
print (df2)
```

This produces:

```
       teams team1 team2
0  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
1  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
2  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
3  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
4  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
5  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
6       None   NaN   NaN
```

Hope this is useful to you and if you need help to apply this to your example let me know.